# How can multiple -- but not all -- values of a DataFrame row be updated using a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ["Norway"     , 7.537, 1.5, 3.0],
             ["Denmark"    , 7.522, 1.2, 3.1],
             ["Switzerland", 7.494, 1.5, 2.8],
             ["Finland"    , 7.469, 1.6, 2.9],
             ["Netherlands", 7.377, 1.5, 3.0],
         ],
         columns = [
             "country",
             "variable_1",
             "variable_2",
             "variable_3",
         ]
    )
```

How could I neatly update, say, the row for Norway with the values `{"variable_2": 1.6, "variable_3": 2.9}` while ensuring that the existing `variable_1` value doesn't get changed?

I was toying with the following terminology:

```
country_to_update = "Norway"
values_to_update  = {"variable_2": 1.6, "variable_3": 2.9}

df.query("country == @country_to_update").iloc[0] = pd.Series(values_to_update)
```

This results in the following error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a general solution

```
df.loc[df.country == country_to_update, values_to_update.keys()] = values_to_update.values()

Out[]: 
       country  variable_1 variable_2 variable_3
0       Norway       7.537        1.6        2.9
1      Denmark       7.522        1.2        3.1
2  Switzerland       7.494        1.5        2.8
3      Finland       7.469        1.6        2.9
4  Netherlands       7.377        1.5          3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a series, then extract index and values:

```
country_to_update = 'Norway'
values_to_update = {'variable_2': 1.6, 'variable_3': 2.9}

s = pd.Series(values_to_update)

df.loc[df['country'] == country_to_update, s.index] = s.values

print(df)

       country  variable_1  variable_2  variable_3
0       Norway       7.537         1.5         3.0
1      Denmark       7.522         1.2         3.1
2  Switzerland       7.494         1.5         2.8
3      Finland       7.469         1.6         2.9
4  Netherlands       7.377         1.5         3.0
```